# Tkinter window is stuck and does not respond to directions

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying to build a snake game, but tkinker window gets stuck after game starts. Initially code use to work fine, but now as i started adding more functions, it got stuck. Please help me find the issue

```
def start():
    pass

def down_move():
    if snake.heading() == 0 or snake.heading() == 180:
        snake.setheading(270)    
def up_move():
    if snake.heading() == 0 or snake.heading() == 180:
        snake.setheading(90)
def left_move():
    if snake.heading() == 90 or snake.heading() == 270:
        snake.setheading(180)
def right_move():
    if snake.heading() == 90 or snake.heading() == 270:
        snake.setheading(0)
text.write("Start the game", align = "center", font=("Arial", 50, "bold"))
wn.onkey(start, 'space')
wn.onkey(down_move,'Down')
wn.onkey(up_move,'Up')
wn.onkey(left_move,'Left')
wn.onkey(right_move,'Right')
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

This is direction part of the code

Comment: could You provide [mre]? this is not minimal reproducible example, just a part of Your code

Comment: what is `onkey()`? because it is not a tkinter function. You should try using `wn.bind()`

Comment: You have only change the heading of `snake` but without moving it using `forward()`, so the `snake` will always be in its starting position.

Comment: @acw1668: Yes, adding `forward()` solved the issue

Comment: @Matiiss: `turtle.onkey()`
This function is used to bind fun to the key-release event of the key. In order to be able to register key-events, TurtleScreen must have focus. Its a Turtle function